# Additive bijection between module sets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

[image]

[image]

This is already been solved, but lacks of what is inteded by additive bijection.
Could someone tell me what is the meaning of the map?

(like how would I read that, in the sense of how is the connection between the remainders and to the module of 6)
(Also, why was $3^{n}$ used?)

The simpler the explanation the better.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking what "additive bijection" means (it seems to be a rather strange term for group isomorphism here), or for intuition about the particular $T$ defined in the solution?

Comment: Both of those things, there was like no explanation at all.